# WPF dock control to cell in grid

Tags: wpf-controls

If I have a 2 by 2 Grid how do I get a button to fill the entire cell? Do I have to use a trigger? How would I get the column's width in that case?

Thanks 
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button` by default will consume the entire cell.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button></Button>
    </Grid>
```

You can get the columns width by accessing the `ColumnDefinitions` collection.

```
Grid g = new Grid();
g.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width;
```

Comment: That's it. I added a button from the toolbox and it automatically set width, height, margin and horizontal/vertical alignment. Removing all of these allowed the button to fill the entire cell. Thanks